# Second countable profinite topological space any equivalence class is a finite union of basic open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a profinite space.(i.e. $X$ is the inverse limit of finite discrete space.) Suppose $X$ is 2nd countable. Then fix any open equivalence relation $R$ on $X$. Pick $x\in X$. Then $Rx\subset X$ is a finite union of basic open sets.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $Rx$ equivalence class is a finite union of basic open sets?

$\textbf{Q':}$ It follows that there are only countably many open equivalence relation on $X$. What cardinality arithmetic is used here? I knew $X$ is compact and there are only finite covering required. How do I know there is a countably many open relations?

Ref. Profinite Groups Luis Ribes, Chpt 1

Comment: Define what you mean by an open equivalence relation?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $R$ is open if $Rx\subset X$ is open where $Rx$ denotes the elements equivalent to $x$ under relation $R$.

Comment: So there are only finitely many distinct classes by compactness.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So the reasoning is picking a particular equivalence relation and use inverse limit can be approximated by cofinal limit. This pick out a particular cofinal inverse system starting with that choice of equivalence relation and every others are refinement of that equivalence relation. Is this correct?

Comment: I don’t understand your point, sorry. Why $Rx$ would be a finite union of basic open sets?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $X$ is compact. $Rx$ is open equivalence. Then $X$ is finite disjoint union of classes by $Rx$. So $Rx$ is closed as well. Then $Rx$ is compact. $Rx$ must be covered by finite number of basic open sets. Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Q has been answered by the above comments. We know that there are only finitely many equivalence classes, each of these being the finite union of basic open sets.

$X$ has a countable base $\mathcal{B}$, therefore the set of all finite sequences in $\mathcal{B}$ is also countable and we conclude that the set $\mathcal{B}^\ast$ of all finite unions of basic open sets must be countable. Hence the set $\mathcal{B}^{\ast \ast}$ of all finite sequences in $\mathcal{B}^\ast$ is countable. The set of open equivalence relations on $X$ can be identified with a subset of $\mathcal{B}^{\ast \ast}$. This answers Q'.